# Specifying C compiler for setup.py compilation

Tags: python, visual-studio, github, distutils

Is there something I can do, (either by setting an environment variable, running a command before running Python, or adding some code to my `setup.py`) to tell Python I want `setup.py` to use a different version of the compiler.

I can see that `distutils` on this Windows machine (a Github runner on Azure) is using version 14.35.32215 of the compiler and linker.

```
>>> import distutils.ccompiler as cc
>>> compiler = cc.new_compiler()
>>> compiler.initialize()
>>> compiler.cc
'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe'
>>> compiler.linker
'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe'
```

I can also see that this machine has multiple compiler versions available.

```
C:\Users\fyellin>dir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\"
 Volume in drive C is Windows
...
12/20/2023  08:29 AM    <DIR>          .
10/10/2023  10:41 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/10/2023  11:04 PM    <DIR>          14.16.27023
10/10/2023  11:05 PM    <DIR>          14.29.30133
10/10/2023  10:47 PM    <DIR>          14.35.32215
10/10/2023  11:09 PM    <DIR>          14.37.32822
```

When I look at the file [`msvccompiler.py`](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl/blob/master/_msvccompiler.py), I find myself completely lost as to how it found this particular MSVC directory and why it decided to use version 14.35.32215 in this directory.  It seems to go deeper into Windows internals than I expected.

Is there some way of changing the compiler version? Where does this version number come from?